# How is dependent function type for a constant family equal to ordinary function type?

Tags: functions, computer-science, type-theory, homotopy-type-theory

On page 34 of the [Homotopy Type Theory book](https://hott.github.io/book/nightly/hott-ebook-1263-g5378ede.pdf), they say if $B : A \to \mathcal{U}$ is the constant family $B(x) = B_0$, then $\Pi_{(x:A)}(B(x))$ still takes $x \in A$ into $\mathcal{U}$ namely to the element $B_0$.  So how is this pi-type equivalent to $(A \to B)$?  Is it a mistake in the book?

Comment: It's an abuse of notation: in your notation, $\prod_{x:A} B(x)$ is equivalent to $A \rightarrow B_0$ in this case.

Comment: @Z.A.K. are you saying an abuse of notation is part of the theory?  This doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @Z.A.K. Okay, I think I get it now.  $\pi_{x:A} B(x) : \mathcal{U}$ just says that pi-types are another type, must have read that wrong.  And $\pi_{x:A} B(x) \equiv (A \to B(x))$ where $B(x)$ depends on the input.  I think I get it now

Comment: Yep, your second comment is spot-on.